# JSF, PrimeFaces, For Loop to draw multiple LineCharts results in memory leak

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i face a issue related to memory consumption, drawing 60 LineCharts will consume more than 600 MB of Ram.

used software:

- firefox ( vers 52.6 ) and chromium ( vers. 64.0.3282 )
- primeface 6.2
- java 1.8

Issue description:

- the issue occurs immediately after opening the website the first time
- a second issue occurs after clicking the 'reload current page' button of the webbroser (refreshing the website). The total memory utilization will be aggregated each time. e.g

  - before loading the website the memory usage was 2,3 Gig
  - after loading the website the first time, the memory utilization jumps to 3,0 Gig
  - after refreshing the website the first time, the memory utilization jumps to 3,8 Gig
  - after refreshing a second time, the memory utilization jumps to 4,4 Gig

The memory issue manifests in the webbrowser process (client site). The Wildfly running on another server is doing fine (server side).

Code and UI description:

[image]

bean code snippet ( request scope )

```
    public List<LineChartModel> getDataModelShowingThePortfolioOfThisInvestor () {
    //return this.getDataModelShowingThePortfolioOfThisInvestor("Warren Buffett");

    listModel.clear();

    for (int i=0;i<60;i++){
        data = new ChartSeries();
        model = new LineChartModel();

        data.set("2004", 1000);
        data.set("2005", 1170);
        data.set("2006", 660);
        data.set("2007", 1030);
        data.set("2008", 1170);
        data.set("2009", 660);
        data.set("2010", 1030);

        model.addSeries(data);

        model.setTitle(new Integer(i).toString());
        model.setLegendPosition("e");
        model.setLegendPlacement(LegendPlacement.OUTSIDEGRID);
        model.setShowPointLabels(false);
        model.setZoom(true);
        //Y-Axis settings
        Axis yAxis = model.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
        yAxis.setLabel("Stock Volume");
        //X-Axis settings
        DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis();
        xAxis.setTickAngle(-50);
        xAxis.setTickFormat("%y %b");
        //add axes to model 
        model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);

        listModel.add(model);

    }

    return listModel;

}
```

jsf template code snippet

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
  <h:head>
    <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    <title><ui:insert name="title"> Beta Application </ui:insert></title>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:growl id="message"></p:growl>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <ui:insert name="center" />
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
   </h:head>
</h:html>
```

jsf code snippet

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="center">
               <ui:repeat var="model" value="#{primefaceChartController.getDataModelShowingThePortfolioOfThisInvestor()}" varStatus="status">
                    <p:chart type="line" model="#{model}" style="height:300px;"/>
               </ui:repeat>            
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

when the jsf code snippet is changed to exclude the template, the cumulative memory usage issue will no longer occur after the site is refreshed. The memory utilization will be e.g.

- before loading the website the memory usage was 2,4 Gig
- after loading the website the first time, the memory utilization jumps to 3,1 Gig
- after the first refresh of the website, memory usage temporarily drops for a few seconds and then increases to 3.1 gig
- after a second refresh, the memory usage drops for a few seconds and then increases to 3.1 gig

jsf code snippet ( template removed )

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <ui:repeat var="model"
        value="#{primefaceChartController.getDataModelShowingThePortfolioOfThisInvestor()}"
        varStatus="status">
        <p:chart type="line" model="#{model}" style="height:300px;" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

Comment: Start by telling if the 'memory leak' is client or server-side. And try removing the template and the c:set etc

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, sorry i forgot to mention, the memory issue occurs in the web browser ( i added a screenshot )

Comment: Checked the second part of my comment? Effectively making a [mcve]

Comment: good point, i may need to rephrase my question, it looks like the issue is caused by the <ui:repeat> code. Is there maybe a better/safer way to print multiple LineCharts on the same page ?  ( maybe by returning through the java code a different jsf element type ?

Comment: descriptions have been revised and a general code example added

Comment: So you don't have this problem if you don't use a template?

Comment: Or no PrimeFaces  layout

Comment: And please check how often `getDataModelShowingThePortfolioOfThisInvestor` is called

Comment: correct, after removing the template, the gc works fine again

Comment: In your initial Q you have 2 major errors. You manually included jQuery AND you have the layout in an `h:head`. Learn to make a [mcve]... always

Comment: fair point. I have read the instructions to create Minimal,Complete and Verifiable example and will stick to it. Many thanks for your help.  

I am surprised regarding the total memory consumption of 600 MB for 60 graphs, is there maybe a last remaining bug left inside the above code or would 10 MB per chart be an to expected and valid ram consumption ?

Comment: question adjusted ( title changed )

Comment: Try with a plain jqplot (that is what PrimeFaces uses). Then you know if it is in there or in something that PF does wrong

Comment: Oh and please revert the title... and add the 'edit' as an answer. Effectively your original question is solved! And please please please check if the template was the cause or the fact that you had the code in the `h:head`. And create a new question for your... well... new question abourt the general memory consumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually included jQuery and put the layout in an `<h:head>` Tag. This leads to the aggregated total memory utilization each time after clicking the 'reload current page' button of the web browser (refreshing the website).Thank you very much Kukeltje for your help